# C# ZipArchive losing data

Tags: c#, zip, c#-ziparchive

I'm trying to copy the contents of one Excel file to another Excel file while replacing a string inside of the file on the copy. It's working for the most part, but the file is losing 27 kb of data. Any suggestions?

```
public void ReplaceString(string what, string with, string path) {
    List < string > doneContents = new List < string > ();
    List < string > doneNames = new List < string > ();
    using(ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(_path, ZipArchiveMode.Read)) {
        int count = archive.Entries.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.Entries[i];

            using(var entryStream = entry.Open())
            using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(entryStream)) {
                string txt = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if (txt.Contains(what)) {
                    txt = txt.Replace(what, with);
                }
                doneContents.Add(txt);
                string name = entry.FullName;
                doneNames.Add(name);
            }
        }
    }

    using(MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        using(ZipArchive newArchive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true, Encoding.UTF8)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < doneContents.Count; i++) {
                int spot = i;
                ZipArchiveEntry entry = newArchive.CreateEntry(doneNames[spot]);

                using(var entryStream = entry.Open())
                using(var sw = new StreamWriter(entryStream)) {
                    sw.Write(doneContents[spot]);
                }
            }
        }

        using(var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)) {
            zipStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            zipStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

I've used Microsoft's DocumentFormat.OpenXML and Excel Interop, however, they are both lacking in a few main components that I need.

Update:

```
using(var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)) {
    var wrapper = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
    wrapper.AutoFlush = true;
    zipStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    zipStream.CopyTo(wrapper.BaseStream);
    wrapper.Flush();
    wrapper.Close();
}
```

Comment: are you actually missing any data? You're compressing, so you will end up with different file sizes if you change the data within.

Comment: I'm actually only changing the text from "Template_x_1" to "Template_x_2"

Comment: Is there a problem other than "the file sizes are different"? If that's the only problem, rejoice in 27k saved!

Comment: Yes, since I'm changing the text inside of the xlsx file, when I launch the new xlsx file in Excel, I get an error that says, "We found some problems with the content in...", but I don't understand why that would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the process without changing the string and see if the file size is the same. If so then it would seem that your copy is working correctly, however as Marc B suggested, with compression, even a small change can result in a larger change in the overall size.

Comment: I did take out the string replace, so no changes were being made, but I was still left with the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried with other variants of the file and is it always 27k lost? If so that would sugest some of the stream buffer is not being flushed to the file at the end of the process.

Comment: Yes I've tried other variants of the file. That's a good point, where would you recommend doing the stream buffer flush?

Comment: Ahhh ok, I notice your not using a wrapper for your output. If you consume your filestream in a FileWriter that should flush the buffer to the file when you close it. Or you can optionally call the flush at the end of the write process.

Comment: Would you mind showing me with an example? Thanks for your help, I think your right.

Comment: do you mean a StreamWriter instead of a FileWriter?

Comment: Yes sorry, getting my languages confused

Comment: So how would you recommend writing that wrapper?

Comment: something like: var wrapper = new FileWriter(fileStream); sorry for the rubbish formatting. I'm using a mobile :(

Comment: Are you closing the file after you finish? And did you try flushing the fileStream object (fileStream.flush())?

Comment: So this is what I'm doing, see the update in the question

Comment: Yeah that would do it, guess that didn't work. I'll have another think.

Comment: I'm willing to accept that the lose of data from the file is compression, but then I wonder if Excel is doing some sort of CRC check when you open it which is giving you the error. Either way, is there a way to recover the document after the process? If not you might have to switch to another method like using a VBA macro to do this :(

Comment: So we figured out the issue, the code worked fine, the template Excel file that we were working with was corrupt. That didn't even cross my mind Thanks for your help.